# Google Scripts Date Conversion Very Slow

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this code grab the Month from Column A and Write in Column B. It works...but it is extremely slow, any suggestion on how to improve?

I tried the utility function (Utilities.formatDate(oldDate, timeZone, "MMM") but very slow as well.

Thanks!

```
function Change_to_Month() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
let row = 1;
let col = 1;

var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();

for (row=1; row<lastrow +1; row++) {
  var oldDate = sheet.getRange(row, col).getValue();
  let newDate= oldDate.toLocaleDateString('en-us',{month:"long"});
  var cell = sheet.getRange(row,col+1);
  cell.setValue(newDate);
}
};
```

4/26/23 4:53    April
4/26/23 4:53    April
4/26/23 3:15    April
4/25/23 19:02   April
3/23/23 2:35    March
3/22/23 14:05   March
3/20/23 22:32   March
3/20/23 22:32   March
2/17/23 13:17   February
2/16/23 16:28   February
2/16/23 11:14   February
2/15/23 23:32   February
1/31/23 21:35   January
1/31/23 6:12    January

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, `getValue` and `setValue` are used in a loop. In this case, the process cost will be high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4) I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue. In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function Change_to_Month() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  let row = 1;
  let col = 1;
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();

  // I modified the below script.
  var range = sheet.getRange(row, col, lastrow);
  var values = range.getValues().map(([a]) => [a.toLocaleDateString('en-us', { month: "long" })]);
  range.offset(0, 1).setValues(values);
}
```

- By this modification, the values are retrieved and the expected values are retrieved from the retrieved values. And, those values are put in the right side column.

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Hi, thank you. Same as below, still taking 5 secs to go through the 14 lines....

Comment: @Moncholero Thank you for replying. About `Hi, thank you. Same as below, still taking 5 secs to go through the 14 lines....`, when I tested my proposed script, even when 1000 rows are processed, the process time is about 2 seconds. So, in this case, I'm worried that the process cost might depend on your actual Spreadsheet. So, please create a new Spreadsheet and put the date values to the column "A" and test the script again.

Comment: You are correct! I tested in a new spreadsheet and it took no time. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

the reason your script is taking long is because each time your code calls the getRange() it is calling the google service and that is very time comsumig. It is always advisable to use javascript operations. Try this:

```
function Change_to_Month() {

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const row = 1;
  const col = 1;

  const sheetValues = sheet.getRange(row,col,sheet.getLastRow() - 1).getValues(); //Gets all values on Column 1
  const valsToPaste = [];

  //loop trhough all values
  for (var i = 0; i < sheetValues.length; i++) {

     //push new values in the valsToPaste
     valsToPaste.push([sheetValues[i][0].toLocaleDateString('en-us',{month:"long"})]);

   }

   sheet.getRange(row,col+1,valsToPaste.length).setValues(valsToPaste); //Paste values in the sheet

 }
```

You can check the google documentation here: [Google Documentaion](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. It is still taking 5 seconds to loop through the 14 lines, isn't still too much? I'm new to google scripts...